# Uniqueness of the limit in measure on a NON-sigma-finite space

Tags: limits, pointwise-convergence

Limits in measure on a non-$\sigma$-finite measure space $(X, \mathcal{A} , \mu)$ need not
be unique.

May someone explain me why, better with an example?

Is it possible that, in the case of non $\sigma$-finite measure space, the convergence almost everywhere doesn't imply the convergence in probability?

Comment: "Limits in measure on a non-$\sigma$-finite measure space $(X, \mathcal{A} , \mu)$ need not be unique". What is your meaning of "limits in measure"? Can you give an example?

Comment: I asked since it's written on the book, but I neither know the meaning of that.

Comment: Which book, may I ask?

Comment: Measures, Integrals & Martingales (2nd edition), Renè L.Schilling, page 262.

Comment: I could not get hold of that book yet. Could you send the text on a few pages to nicetechie@ymail.com? I guess that is ok with copyright.

Comment: About "limits in measure" and "convergence in probability".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a non $\sigma$-finite measure space, the convergence almost everywhere doesn't imply the convergence in probability. Consider $(\Bbb R, \mathscr P(\Bbb N),\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is the counting measure. Since $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, $\alpha$ is not $\sigma$-finite. Let $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 
0 &\text{if } x\le n,\\ 1 &\text{if } x >n.
\end{cases}$$
Then $\{f_n\}_n$ converges to $0$ everywhere. However, $\{f_n\}_n$ does not converge to $0$ in probability.

In fact, the convergence almost everywhere doesn't necessarily imply the convergence in probability for a $\sigma$-finite measure. For example, $\{f_n\}_n$ does not converge to $0$ in probability with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$, either.

Comment: So basically the fact that the measure space is infinite would be a sufficient condition in order to say that the convergence almost everywhere doesn't imply the converge in probability?

Comment: Another question. In the example you show, is it also possibile to say that there's the convergence pointwise? My reasoning is: If i fix "x" and I push n to $\infty$, I will surely find an n > x, and for that reason the lim would be zero.

Comment: @GabrielePillitteri To your first comment: Sort of conceptually, not mathematically. For example, consider the space of one point with measure infinity, where convergence almost everywhere implies "complete" convergence.

Comment: To second comment: yes, $\{f_n\}_n$ converges to $0$ pointwise.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again. Everything's clear and I appreciate that. Do you mind If I ask you the proof of why there's no convergence in probability?